# Tkinter how to distinguish between <Key> and <Control-Key> bindings?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

This might be a simple answer.

I have a text widget which i want to bind any alphanumeric keyboard key (a-zA-Z0-9_ and rest of regular keys) to a specific method, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to another method.

Using `widget.bind("<Key>", method)` will create the following:

1. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will invoke `method` twice, one for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (`event.keysym = Control_L, event.char = None`) and second for <kbd>F</kbd> (`event.keysym = f, event.char = <invalid>`)
2. Click <kbd>F</kbd> will invoke `method` (`event.keysym = f, event.char = f`)

Is there a way to distinguish between the two scenarios?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can manually (or in `for` loop) set `<Control-f>` and `<f>` and others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind `<Control-f>` and `<f>` (and the same with other keys).

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def key_f(event):
    print('key: f')

def key_shift_f(event):
    print('key: Shift + f')

def key_control_f(event):
    print('key: Control + f')

def key_control_shift_f(event):
    print('key: Control+Shift + f')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

#root.bind("<f>", key_f) # it works too
#root.bind("<F>", key_shift_f) # it works too
root.bind("f", key_f)
root.bind("F", key_shift_f)
root.bind("<Control-f>", key_control_f)
root.bind("<Control-F>", key_control_shift_f)

root.mainloop()
```

Or you can use `event.state & 4` to recognize key with `Control`.

You need bit-wise `&` because it keeps information about other special keys

(see `Masks/Modifier` on http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/event-handlers.html)

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def method(event):
    print('-----')
    print('[DEBUG] event.char  :', event.char)
    print('[DEBUG] event.keysym:', event.keysym)
    print('[DEBUG] event.state :', event.state, '=', bin(event.state))

    if event.char: # skip Control_L, etc.

        # if you need `& 5` then it has to be before `& 4` 

        if event.state & 5 == 5: # it needs `== 5` because `& 5` can give results `5`, `4` or `1` which give `True` or `0` which gives `False`
            print('method: Control+Shift +', event.keysym)

        elif event.state & 4: # it doesn't need `== 4` because `& 4` can give only results `4` or `0`
            print('method: Control +', event.keysym)

        elif event.state & 1: # it doesn't need `== 1` because `& 1` can give only results `1` or `0`
            print('method: Shift +', event.keysym)

        else:
            print('method:', event.keysym)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

root.bind("<Key>", method)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I changed `event.state == 20` into `event.state & 4` to work with other special keys: